# How to get the FormatCondition Object

Tags: excel, vba

I want to read out the color that the conditional format sets for a particular cell.

Example,commentary, and code of what I've tried below. Note: Selection is simply a cell that contains a conditional format.

How can I get a refrence to a `FormatCondition` Object? What am I missing/ not seeing? Error on last line...

```
Sub FC_Test()
Dim fc As FormatConditions
Dim fco As Object
Dim c As Object
Dim myRng As Range
Set myRng = Selection 'Any cell with a conditional format

Debug.Print "FC Count: " & myRng.Resize(1, 1).FormatConditions.Count

'Finds all FC on the sheet
Set fc = Cells.FormatConditions
Debug.Print TypeName(fc) 'Returns: FormatConditions

'Finds first applied format condition...
'...oddly this is not a FormatCondition (member of hte FC collection),
' but the name of the type of format condition applied.. i.e. "ColorScale", etc.
Set c = Cells.FormatConditions(1)
Debug.Print TypeName(c) 'Returns: ColorScale

'Finds FC in selected range.
Set fc = myRng.Resize(1, 1).FormatConditions
Debug.Print TypeName(fc) 'Returns: FormatConditions
Debug.Print TypeName(fc.Item(1)) 'Returns: ColorScale
Set fco = fc(1)
Debug.Print TypeName(fco) 'Returns: ColorScale

Set fco = Nothing
For Each fco In fc
    Debug.Print TypeName(fco) 'Returns: ColorScale
Next fco

Dim fcs As FormatCondition
Set fcs = myRng.Resize(1, 1).FormatConditions(1) 'Type Mismatch:13

End Sub
```

Comment: `FormatConditions` collection can contain different type of objects: `FormatCondition`,`Databar`, `ColorScale`, `IconSetCondition`, .... Those are different classes with different properties, so I am afraid you cannot get `FormatCondition` object when the rule is color scale.

Comment: But if you only want to get color set by conditional formatting you may want to have a look at [Range.DisplayFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat)

Comment: Range.DisplayFormat will get what I need. Interestingly, it can not be used froma UDF called from the worksheet. So I'll next need to find a workaround for that. Please put your comment as the answer so I can market it. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to have an UDF returning values depending on cell color - it is likely to cause many problems - for example refreshing UDF value on color change. A better approach would be to have the same logic in the UDF as in conditional formatting.

Comment: Wouldn't that essentially require reinventing the wheel (conditional formatting)? I was trying to avoid that by just getting the color from CF

Comment: It looks like circular reference - you want to have some rules based on values to change colors and then use those colors to calculate values. From my experience the best way is to make it one way road - colors depend on values, the other way is always causing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormatConditions` collection can contain different type of objects: `FormatCondition`,`Databar`, `ColorScale`, `IconSetCondition`, ....

Those are different classes with different properties - the type of object depends on conditional formatting rule kind.

It means that it is not possible to get `FormatCondition` object when there is different (for example color scale) rule applied. 
To read color of the cell (no matter if it is normal or conditional formatting) [Range.DisplayFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat) can be used.

Answer (score 0):

[FormatConditions object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions)

```
With myRng.FormatConditions(1)
    .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    .Font.ColorIndex = 26
End With
```

Comment: Your answer would set the object. I'm trying to read it out. Also, when i do run it in my code, i get a run time error 438